# How to set promo can be used x times for each day in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

Can i set cart price rule for customer that goes with condition like this:

- Each customer can only use this promo x times for each day

Comment: It is possible but you want to buy extension or create custom module for that

Comment: @KamleshSolanki custom module